# SVG scrolling in firefox/chrome/IE

Tags: svg

I have a rather large tree diagram modeled in SVG.

It renders well, with vertical scrolling as desired, in IE-9.

In Chrome and Firefox, not so. No scrolling in Chrome but zooming out lets me see a little more.
In Firefox, it is only showing a token amount of the vertical space.

I assume I am missing some attributes in the "svg" element to make it show up correctly in Chrome/Firefox but not sure what.

Here is how the doc source starts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="100%" width="100%" style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;"  >

  <rect x="685" y="15" rx="10" ry="10" width="380" height="116" style="fill:lightgrey;stroke-width:5;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  <text x="777" y="38" fill="black"  font-size = "18"  font-family = "sans-serif" font-weight="bold">Folder</text>
  <text x="960" y="38" fill="black"  font-size = "18"  font-family = "sans-serif" font-weight="bold">Content</text>

  <rect x="700" y="45" rx="10" ry="10" width="200" height="75" style="fill:powderblue;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  ................... and so on for 150000 lines ...................
```

Any ideas on what can be added so it will render in Chrome/Firefox as it does in IE-9?

Comment: Firefox does not currently support overflow on an outer <svg> element. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=378923

Answer (score 2):

Hard coding values into "height" and "width" solved the acute problem of no scrolling in Chrome and Firefox.

Making the script that generates the svg smarter to put in appropriate values for "height" and "width" is a better solution but for now, just setting
**height="50000"  width="2400"**
instead of using the **%** values, worked for me.